# move_uploaded_file doesnt work suddenly

Tags: php

hello every one i am newbie i try to create a website i used this function move_uploaded_file its worke with some probleme like french caracter not supported but its move the file from my computer to the destination then i changed some code in php.ini to solve the problem then i uninstall the wamp server and reinstall it again no this function does to resolve the problem i simplyfied the code but still not working

```
if(isset($_POST['ajouter'])){
    $file= $_FILES['cour']['name']; 
    $file_loc= $_FILES['cour']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['cour']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['cour']['type'];
    $fichier = 'cours_pdf/';

    move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$fichier.$file);
    $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_uploads (file,type,size,categorie) 
    VALUES(:file,:file_type,:file_size,'defau')");  
    $q->bindValue(':file',$file);
    $q->bindValue(':file_type',$file_type);
    $q->bindValue(':file_size',$file_size);
    $q->execute();
}
```

and the html code

```
<div id="forms" style="max-width:350px;" >
    <form class="form-horizontal"  action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="btn btn-success btn-file">Browse 
            <input type="file" name="cour" hidden>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="categorie">choisir la categorie ou enregistrer votre cours</label>
        <select  class="form-control" name="categorie" required>
            <option value="cardiologie">cardiologie</option>
            <option value="chirurgie_general">chirurgie_general</option>
            <option value="chirurgie_thoracique">chirurgie_thoracique</option>
            <option value="dermatologie">dermatologie</option>
            <option value="endocrinologie">endocrinologie</option>
            <option value="gynecologie">gynecologie</option>
            <option value="hematologie">hematologie</option>
            <option value="infectiologie">infectiologie</option>
            <option value="neurologie">neurologie</option>
            <option value="orl">orl</option>
            <option value="pediatrie">pediatrie</option>
            <option value="urologie">urologie</option>
            <option value="gastro_enterologie">gastro_enterologie</option>
            <option value="psychiatrie">psychiatrie</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="ajouter" value="envoyer">
    </form>
</div>
```

please help me iam siack here and forgive my weak english thanks

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: no i receive my one message that the upload was failled i removed it to simplyfie the code

Comment: Check the variables `$file_loc` and `$fichier.$file` - if they contain paths that exist in your system? Also, if you have _french characters_ in the pathname they can cause the problem and should be changed to normal characters.

Comment: for the french caracter its about the name of the files now i try just with english same thing the repertorie cours_pdf in the same level of the scripts

Comment: are there other function to move the files

Answer (score 1):

The field for inputting file is hidden, remove `hidden` from your input.

```
 <label class="btn btn-success btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" name="cour"> <!-- removed hiddedn -->
 </label>
```

Comment: i didnt change anything in the html code it was working with the hidden input if i remove hidden i will have a bad look for my site i dont think thats the problem because the treatement with database work correctly thank you brother i am sure that the probleme came from the function move_uploaded_file it self

Comment: Ok, There's no way you can upload a file without an input.

Comment: so why i can insert the name in my database correctly the input exist but its hidden because this is the architecture of bootstrap any way i did remove the hidden   same result

Comment: because the insert is not a file

Comment: i remove it same  result  the problem start when i touch php.ini  but i uninstal all the server and reinstall it again

Comment: no error no warning just a white page when i look to the repertorie cours_pdf i find no file uploaded